# Provisioning profile doesn't support the Push Notifications capability

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have a share extension, with a provisioning profile, which should work.

However, some reason xcode thinks Notifications is turned on for this target.  Notifications is in fact turned on for the app, but NOT the share extension (which its complaining about).

Ive disabled notifications for this share extension target, both in developer.apple and in the capabilities section, disabled automatic signing, and its STILL complaining about it.

[image]

[image]

and in developer.apple:

[image]
How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your .entitlements file ? Maybe something there.

Comment: For me, when I changed the bundle ID, it worked.